# Odd problem with implementing max with for loop

Tags: java, loops, max

I spend the last hour doing trial and error with this problem with no avail. We have to, using general coding guidelines (like scan.nextDouble) instead of actual numbers, find the max of a certain number of double values. The only catch is that we can only add code at a certain point. (where the ... is)

```
double value, valMax;
    int n;
    n = scan.nextInt();
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
       value = scan.nextDouble();
        ...
    }
```

Where the first value read in is an int and that is the amount of doubles to be entered.

It is difficult because I have to find a way to initialize valMax inside the loop without messing up anything else.

This is what I have been working with, but with nothing working for me.

```
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {
      value = scan.nextDouble();
      if(j == 0)
      {
       valMax = scan.nextDouble();
       j++;
      }
      else
      {
       continue;
      }
      if(value >= valMax)
      {
       valMax = value;
      }
   }
```

Example input:

```
5    -4.7  -9.2  -3.1  -8.6  -5.0
```

Where -3.1 is the max and 5 is the count of following numbers.

Comment: I must say, this is a pretty weird homework problem. Because of the contraints you won't actually be able to use `valMax` anywhere after the loop (i.e. print it out) because it may not have been initialized.

Comment: Well the problem does not state it has to be printed out, just that it has to store the maximum value into valMax. A note on the bottom of the problem states "How valMax is initialized is important."

Comment: +1 for using the homework tag (:D)

Comment: @drachenstern: Actually, ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Comment: @Roger Page ~ `/facepalm` then. Thanks for the headsup.

Comment: Turns out the professor made a mistake on the assignment. It was meant for double value, valMax = 0. lol

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems like a good start.

To help solve your problem, consider:

- Why did you put in the extra `j++`? Do you really need it? (Hint: no ;-) )
- What will the loop do for `j>0` (i.e. after the first iteration)?

That should quickly give you a working solution.

Comment: i put the extra j++ because i used two values in the first run. Like i said it was me doing trial and error. (i think this was try #8)

Comment: I only resort to trial and error when my books, notes, previous knowledge, and friends fail.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to set the `valMax` before the loop? Because in that case you can just do

```
valMax = Double.MIN_VALUE
```

and just forget about strange things by doing a normal comparison `value > valMax`.

If you are not your approach is how you should do but two things:

- you shouldn't care about incrementing with `j++` since the `for` loop will care about it by itself..
- having a `else { continue; }` will make the body of the `for` jump to next iteration without caring about code that is after the continue. Are you sure that is what you want to do?

I think that you can initialize to `Double.MIN_VALUE` at first iteration (`j == 0`) and just behave normally afterwards: the only thing you need is that `valMax` is initialized before the first comparison with value, not before the scan from stdin..

Comment: No we cannot exit any existing code, only add code where the ... is.

Comment: @John ~ You may consider the check if valMax has not been set to any value, then what might it be? Or in other words, is there a value valMax may have that would indicate it has not been intialized? Can you test to see if it is currently set to that value, and would therefore need to be initialized? [don't think this is impossible, it's really a simple two lines of code that needs to be inserted]

Comment: I have no idea. I have no idea why he would assign this and not talk about it in class. I might try going to his office hour tomorrow. I am stumped.

Comment: hint: `if (valMax == null) {valMax = new double; valMax = 0;}` (ok, that's not perfect, but that's roughly how I would check to see if the value hadn't been assigned.

Comment: Actually, you don't need `Double.MIN_VALUE`, at `j==0` the max known value is the current number in `value`.

Comment: @John: Knowing when to ask for help is key, and knowing who to ask for help is just is important (this type of question is really about the requirements rather than the programming, and your professor or TAs know those better than you can explain them to us).  Don't forget that you're paying tuition for the privilege of those office hours.

Comment: @drachenstern I followed what you suggested except I am getting a token error at double with "dimensions expected after this token". I understand where you are coming from, I had tried null earlier but we have not learned about 'new double'. Unless I missed it somewhere in the book...

Comment: in this case `new` should mean to allocate memory for this variable as uninitialized, but I'm only guessing that Java allows the same thing. Try `new double(0)`. You then wouldn't need the second `valMax = 0;` statement

Comment: I tried it, I mean the code overall still functions in my original code, except when I add a System.out.println(valMax) at the bottom after the code, I get an error due to valMax may not have been initialized. That is mainly because if n would = 0, then valMax would not be set, thus not being initialized. Maybe this problem is a trick question.

Comment: That is strange, Java doesn't have the concept of uninitialized constants. If you just declare a `double` it will get `0.0` as default value